# How to "iso-8859-1" encoding a string in jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, encoding, base64

I'm looking for a jQuery(or jQuery plugin) equivalent of this C# code block. What it does is to encode a string to base64 string in iso-8859-1 character set.

```
string authInfo = "encrypted secret";
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
byte[] authBytes = encoding.GetBytes(authInfo);
string encryptedMsg = Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes);
```

Is there a plugin out there that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a jQuery plugin that's close enough to what I need: [Base64 encode and decode](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/base64-encode-and-decode)
It doesn't have an option to specify character set but I can live with it for now. So the jQuery code becomes:

```
authInfo = $.base64.encode(authInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must specify the character encoding of the page (or where ever authInfo is defined) to ISO-8859-1.  You may also specify the character encoding of the  tag for referenced javascript files if authInfo is defined in one of those.

As for base64 encoding, here's a page that has a code snippet that does just that: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html